# get first non-blank value from a specific column, specified by an index. Excel

Tags: excel, array-formulas

This array formula allows me to populate D4 by searching for the first non blank value in Column A (see link - https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-non-blank-value-in-a-list)

`=INDEX(A2:A1000,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A2:A1000),0))`

However, I'd like to refine it such that the column being searched changes depending on the value entered in C4.

For example, if the value in C4 were 1 than I'd get the value 13.86. If the value in C4 were 2 I'd get the value 10. See here -
[click for link to example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To6kE.png)

I tried adapting the above array formula with an IF function but no success. I'm a total novice so be kind :)

`=IF(C4=1,(INDEX(A2:A1000,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A2:A1000)))),IF(C4=1,(INDEX(B2:B1000,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(B2:B1000)))),0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D5 as an array formula (with CSE),

```
=INDEX(A2:B1000, MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(INDEX(A2:B1000, 0, C4)),0), C4)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great!!! Can it be adapted such that it could handle 5 different potential values?

Comment: Did you at least try to widen the columns (keeping in mind that the formulka needs to be pushed over to avoid circualr reference)? Do you understand how C4 works? Did you read the INDEX function documentation on support.office.com?

Comment: i've widened the columns and moved the formula yes, but I'm trying to adapt the rest of the formula based on what i can learn about index. I've never used excel prior to this so its a little slow going!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. It is gonna look daunting but trust me if you look closely it really is a very simple combined with few other formulas

Enter the below formula in `D4` or desired cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,K4,4),"1","")&1&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,K4,4),"1","")&100),MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,K4,4),"1","")&1&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,K4,4),"1","")&100)),0))
```

Here `K4` is my input cell(which is `C4` for your case) and I have considered a range of `1:100` unlike yours of `1:1000`. So change accordingly.

**EXPLANATION**

1. `ADDRESS` function returns a text of address based on input you give. For input 8 it'll give `H1`

`=INDEX(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE("H1","1","")&1&":"&SUBSTITUTE("H1","1","")&100),MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE("H1","1","")&1&":"&SUBSTITUTE("H1","1","")&100)),0))`

2. `SUBSTITUTE` function then strips down the 1 and gives output only `H`, which is then used with `INDIRECT` function to get the range.

`=INDEX(INDIRECT("H"&1&":"&"H"&100),MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(INDIRECT("H"&1&":"&"H"&100)),0))`

`=INDEX(INDIRECT("H1:H100"),MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(INDIRECT("H1:H100")),0))`

Rest is exactly your formula.